# How to restrict optimized value to be greater than 0

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Let's say I need to minimize a function but I want to keep the result above `0`. That is the optimized value should be `>= 0`. I can find stuff on how to constraint the parameters but not the return value itself.

```
def test(params, *args):
    return params[0] + params[1]
minVal = minimize(test, [0.01, 0.02], ...) # I want minVal to be lowest non-negative value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a constraint that forces the objective to be >= 0:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def test(params):
    return params[0] + params[1]

# forces test(params) >= 0
con = [{"type" : "ineq", "fun" : test}]

minVal = minimize(test, x0=[0.01, 0.02], constraints=con)
```